# Jekyll not parsing ## Tags

Tags: jekyll

I have a Jekyll website and everything works fine, just it doesn't parse `<h2>` tags in markdown (I also tried putting the actual HTML and still doesn't work. Example: [here](http://valeit.github.io/apps/) or [here](http://valeit.github.io/apps/patchnotes/). When I test it with a local server everything works though.

[Source code](https://github.com/valeIT/valeIT.github.io/blob/master/apps/index.md) for the `/apps` page:

```
---
layout: page
title: My Apps
---

Here's a list of all my published apps, sorted by platform.

[If you need Support and would like to open a ticket, please go to the Support page.](/support)

Most applications are available in English, Italian and Polish so far.

[Click here to take a look at the Patch Notes](/apps/patchnotes)

{% for member in site.data.apps %}

{% if member.link %}

##{% if member.fontAwesome %}{% for image in member.fontAwesome %}<i class="fa fa-{{ image }}"></i> {% endfor %}{% endif %}<a href="{{ member.link }}">{{ member.name }}</a>
<br><br>
{{ member.description }}   

{% if member.bundleName %}Included in [{{ member.bundleName }}]({{bundleLink }}) bundle.{% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

[[Source for `app/patchnotes`](https://github.com/valeIT/valeIT.github.io/blob/master/apps/patchnotes/index.md) - [Page Layout](https://github.com/valeIT/valeIT.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/page.html)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
## {% if member.fontAwesome %}
```

I just added a whitespace between `##` and `{℅`

Let me know if it works, yeah?

Comment: Works, weird since I'm sure I tried that already before... Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! If you ever get stuck on kramdown, try giving a look at this [cheat sheet](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html). It's useful! Hey, would you mind upvoting my answer too? :) It would help me here at stack overflow.... ;)

Comment: Thanks for upvoting! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Gemfile` includes some dependencies like `bourbon` or `time-to-read`. Those are not supported plugins/gems ([list of gh-pages supported gems/plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/)).

If you leave only github-pages gem in your `Gemfile` and build or serve locally, it fails.
I think that Github pages is also failing but more gracefully.

If you want to work with "exotics" gems, you will have to generate locally and push the generates site on github.

Comment: I'll take a look on this too when I have some time, thanks for bringing it up.