# Github pages cannot display markdown correctly

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am using github pages + jekyll to establish my blog.

It worked properly before  pushed my latest commit. This commit adds a cname file and just edits some words without any alterations over the architecture of my site.

```
-    <h3 class="description">aaaaaaaaaa</h3>
+    <h3 class="description">bbbbbbbbbb</h3>
```

After that markdown does not appear properly.

When I write #head1. It does not appear title head1, it just appears #head1 directly.

[image]

However, if I use jekyll serve build in localhost:4000, it appears correctly.
[image]

This is my _config.yml:

> markdown:      kramdown
>   markdown_ext:  markdown,mkd,mkdn,md
>   textile_ext:   textile
>   highlighter:    pygments

Any ideas what has been causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED!

This is most likely due to [Jekyll 3 upgrade](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2015/10/26/jekyll-3-0-released/) on [GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0).

From May 1st 2016 on, GitHub will not support `rdiscount` nor `redcarpet` anymore. Also, since February 1st, GitHub Pages only supports `rouge`:

> Starting May 1st, 2016, GitHub Pages will only support kramdown,
>   Jekyll's default Markdown engine.
>
> GitHub Pages now only supports
>   Rouge.

You can check this out [here](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0).

In order to deal with it, proceed as the following:

First, try as explained on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35363566/5455207). Instead of `#Heading` you'll write `# Heading`.

Second, adjust your `_config.yml`: change `highlighter` and `markdown` for

```
highlighter: rouge
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Third, to build your site locally, use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/), the method [recommended by GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/):

1. Install Bundler:

   ```
   gem install bundler
   ```
2. Then run `bundle update` - this will update all your gems, including [github-pages](https://github.com/github/pages-gem), if you already have this gem installed locally.
3. Then, create a `Gemfile` (leave it without any file extension) with the following content:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org' 
   gem 'github-pages'
   ```

Save it to your project's root.

4. Then, run `bundle install` on your project. This will create a file called `Gemfile.lock` and will **install all required gems and their dependencies**.
5. Finally, run `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` and you'll be able to view your website locally exactly as you'll view online (when hosting on GitHub).

You should be OK by then!

---

PS. If your project needs more gems, as `jekyll-paginate` or `jekyll-mentions`, you'll need to add them to the `Gemfile`, for example:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
gem 'github-pages'
gem 'jekyll-paginate'
```

Also, add them to your project's `_config.yml`:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-mentions
```

Here you'll see a list of [gem versions currently supported by GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/). Here you read about [Upgrading Jekyll 2 to 3](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/).

Hope to have helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add an whitespace between # and head title as your description in first step. And I edited my config.yml. However, it still not works.  I’m not understand your third step completely and just update my jekyll use `gem update jekyll`. (now jekyll version 3.1.1). In localhost 4000 , it still works.  I found that everything is fine except title marks like # ## ### in a markdown file.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to make it more clear to you. :)

Comment: @lululu Sorry for the delay, I couldn't find some time to do that before. But now I believe the answer is complete. Let me know how does it goes, ok?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: when you said you ran `gem update jekyll` and didn't work, this happened because jekyll wasn't the only gem that needed to be updated. `github-pages` gem was the most important on this case. Also, when you run `bundle install` to your project, it will require the same jekyll version that is currently in use by GH Pages (which is [Jekyll 3.0.3](https://pages.github.com/versions/) now). It is important update all your gems from time to time, so you won't get into trouble: run `bundle update`.

Comment: So sorry for my one week delay. I was faced a problem of ruby in my mac osx. Fortunately, I solved that. After that, I remove my blog’s repository in github and recreate it. Then I absolutely complied with steps in your answer and instructions of docs about github pages to re-establish my blog. IT WORKS!!!  Although I have yet to find the exactly reason of this problem, i will try to figure out that.  Thank you so much, Your answer has been very help to me. And i will adopt it.

Comment: Sorry, I have not enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

A slight observation running my own Jekyll powered github pages blog,

A space between the # representing the heading size, and the heading text is important otherwise the markdown will not display as intended. Therefore with your example, I would display my markdown heading as,

```
# Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast for heading 1

## Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast for heading 2

### Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast for heading 3

#### Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast for heading 4

##### Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast for heading 5
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub support markdown as well jekyll.
First of all rename your file with the **`.md`** extension

If you have `.nojekyll` in your folder it will **disable** njekyll.

Verify that you don't have this is your folder.

---

Read the [docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) && [GitHub relevant doc](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) on how to prepare and deploy

---

> #### Running Jekyll
>
> Use the command git checkout to switch to the default branch that the GitHub Pages build server uses to generate your site. The default branch you switch to depends on the type of GitHub Pages site you're building.
>
> For Project Pages sites, switch to gh-pages.
>   For User Pages or Organization Pages sites, switch to master. For more information, see "User, Organization, and Project Pages".
>
> Use the command bundle exec jekyll serve in the root of your repository to run the GitHub Pages build server with Bundler.
>
> bundle exec jekyll serve
>   Navigate to http://localhost:4000 to see your local site.

Comment: Thank you for you answer to my question.  All file already ended with `md` extension and I’m sure no `.nojekyll` in my folder. It still not works. I plan to read all docs about github pages and jekyll carefully.

Comment: Cool, ill try to help you as much as i can