# Why is my Jekyll blog not on my Github page?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

**http://leongaban.github.io/leongaban-10/** (<- displaying the default github page theme)

[image]

[Here is my repo with a jekyll blog](https://github.com/leongaban/leongaban-10/tree/gh-pages) that works 100% locally, I did create the gh-pages branch. Below is a screenshot of what the blog should look like on my github page:

[image]

Do I need to change anything here in my `_config.yml`?

## Site settings

```
title: Leon Gaban
email: leongaban@gmail.com
description: "Leon Gaban"# this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://leongaban.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
twitter_username: leongaban
github_username:  leongaban

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your repository must end in github.com/github.io i.e. rename your https://github.com/leongaban/leongaban-10/ repo to: https://github.com/leongaban/leongaban.github.io

Comment: I need to add also that my `_site` folder was not being added to the repo, it was listed in the `.gitignore` so I had to remove it from there and now with the correct path and all the files, its working! leongaban.github.com

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `_config.yml`:

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

in order to keep the same markdown GitHub will use.

Also, if it is your user website `username.github.io` it's better move it to a `master` branch. `gh-pages` branch is supposed to be applied to project websites only.

Your `_site` folder is not supposed to be there. It contains the site already build. Normally it's useful for local preview and when you're hosting with a service that doesn't build Jekyll automatically, like an Apache server. Also when you use Jekyll plugins that are not allowed by GitHub, so you choose building the site locally and uploading the static site only to GH.

I see two approaches: weather you remove the `_site` folder and move your project to the master branch, or you remove the rest of the content and upload to your repo only the content of the _site folder (not the folder itself).

Hope to have helped!

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know how the _site worked... so that's cool, Jekyll compiles on github

Comment: Exactly. It's build with bundler via `bundle exec jekyll build`.

Comment: I'm writing quickly from my phone, so I won't be able to provide you with a link, but try googling for "GitHub Pages Jekyll bundle exec" and you will find the GH documentation explaining that.

Comment: Here you'll find the step-by-step on using bundler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35449384/5455207