# Local `jekyll serve` doesn't match Github

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When I run `jekyll serve` locally, I get the following ouput

[local site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT67g.png)

Then when I push to Github and host on Github pages, the sidebar links don't work the same way

[github pages site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U6ux.png)

I'm running jekyll 3.1.1 (latest version) while Github Pages depends on 3.0.3. Do I need to uninstall jekyll and install the older version? Or is there something I can do to make my local and Github pages match?

The repo on github is available at (sorry can only post 2 links)

[github.com/samarthbhaskar/samarthbhaskar.github.io](http://github.com/samarthbhaskar/samarthbhaskar.github.io)

Answer (score 0):

With help from Github, I was able to solve this.

There was a whitespace issue in the front matter of my `index.md` file for the page I was trying to create. I erased and retyped the front matter as:

```
---
layout: page
title: Movie Reviews
---
```

... and that did the trick! Hope this answer helps someone else trying to solve the same issue. Now to figure out what might be going on with my Sublime Text 3 settings to cause white space issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve Jekyll with bundler, so it will reproduce the same environment as GitHub Pages does.

Follow the steps I described on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35449384/5455207)

And you should be ok.

Let me know how it goes for you ok?

Hope to have helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look into serving jekyll with bundler, that will help in future debugging. This time around, it turned out to be a front-matter whitespace issue, which I was able to fix, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35543878/4876551). Appreciate your help!

Comment: I got that! But it's better serve Jekyll with bundler otherwise you might end up facing some errors. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could force your push to the remote repo on github with a git command in order to override any inconsistencies between the local and remote repositories. But glad this worked out for you!

```
git push -f
```