# Why site.baseurl doesn't work on Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

i have been trying to create jekyll site and host on git-pages. Localy everything works fine. But on github-pages works only first pages and 10 newest blog post.
But after going to any of other pages like "Blogas" or "Straipniai" every link starts with 'localhost:4000' and naturaly breaks css, javascript...
And i am not sure where is problem, because everything is same even if i make change in /_includes/header.html site.url to site.baseurl.
Here is [git-hub](https://github.com/InvisibleGhostt/invisibleghostt.github.io)
And [site](http://codas.lt)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you somehow have both a .md and an .html version of the same pages. The .html version you built locally and GH is preferring it. it has localhost in the urls so it won't work. Try deleting the .html files in those sub folders and see what happens. For example, delete the index.html file from `invisibleghostt.github.io/blogas/` and see if that page is fixed.

No idea how you got those files in there, they should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Look, there are a few things you'd better fix on your `_config.yml`:

```
url: "http://codas.lt"     # add the site url

gems:                      # remove `jekyll` from gems
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-gist
  - octopress

include: [".htaccess"]    # remove this line (GitHub Pages does not support .htaccess)
```

The other thing is, you'll need to remove all the folders from the folder `_posts`, as explained [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#my-categories-have-stopped-working):

> If you organized your categories as
>   `/_posts/code/2008-12-24-closures.md`, you will need to restructure your
>   directories to put the categories above the `_posts` directories, as
>   follows: `/code/_posts/2008-12-24-closures.md`.

You are probably working locally with a Jekyll version which diverges from [GitHub Pages'](https://pages.github.com/versions/) (currently is Jekyll 3.0.3). That's why your site works locally and doesn't work there. To avoid that, build Jekyll with Bundler (a dependency manager). On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405657/github-pages-cannot-display-markdown-correctly/35449384#35449384) you can see how to do that, step-by-step.

Hope to have helped! :)

---

*Note: If you get stuck in how to adapt your theme to work with GitHub Pages, you can try [GitLab Pages](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html), as you can easily set the Jekyll version you want to use to build your site. For example, [this project](https://gitlab.com/jekyll-themes/carte-noire) builds the site with Jekyll 2.5.3.*