# Depoying Jekyll themes on github pages - how to get github to treat repo as jekyll site?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, domain-name, static-site

So, I recently purchased a domain on godaddy and I'm trying to get a simple blog-like static site up and running. I tested it out using a 'jekyll now' theme and they both connected! However, the file structure seems a bit different to regular jekyll (it doesn't even have _posts folder- meaning, I have to write my content in the index.html). So now, I'm trying to get it up using regular jekyll (this theme to be specific: http://thephuse.github.io/strange_case/). I downloaded the repo on my machine and yes it does work locally. But when I upload those files from my desktop into a new github repo (named: .github.io) and access the site using https://.github.io, the front page displays but without the formatting or images etc. It also isn't able to open any of the links to the posts- simply displays a 404. I think this means that github is rendering it as a regular html file and not able to make out that this a jekyll theme or maybe something along those lines- but I'm not able to figure out what the issue is and how to resolve it - so I can have the theme up and running as well as connected to my custom domain (which I manage on godaddy btw).

Looking for some senior/experienced guys to throw some light on this issue?

Thanks, appreciate all inputs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are deploying it through `bundle` and you have the `github-pages` gem.

The following steps should be enough to fix you problem:

1. `gem install bundle`
2. `gem update`
3. Create file named **Gemfile** containing:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org' 
   gem 'github-pages'
   ```
4. `bundle install` will now install the specified gem.
5. `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` will show you exactly how the site would look on GitHub-Pages, but locally.

Hope this helps!

For some additional details, you could look at this [great answer by VirtuaCreative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405657/github-pages-cannot-display-markdown-correctly/35449384#35449384), where she explains how you could also add any additional gems, you have used.